# C# forms - Cast a textbox's calculated value into another while typing it

Tags: c#, textbox

I need to cast the sine of an angle typed into one textbox (`angTxtbox`) to another (`sinAngTxtbox`). Some solutions produce a `0` in the second textbox and others just ignore my code and leave it writable.

The below one produces an error:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

at this line: `int v = Convert.ToInt32(sinAngTxtbox.Text);`

Please guide and thanx all, in advance.

```
 private void AngTxtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int v = Convert.ToInt32(sinAngTxtbox.Text);
        sinAngTxtbox.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Sin(v * Math.PI / 180));
    }
```

Comment: And? Was it in the correct format to represent an integer?

Comment: Use a NumericUpDown control instead

Answer (score 0):

Since the input allows a string value, the entered value is not guaranteed to be convertible to an `int`. Check if the value can be converted first, and then perform the operation.

```
private void AngTxtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(int.TryParse(sinAngTxtbox.Text, out int v))
  {
      sinAngTxtbox.Text = Math.Sin(v * Math.PI / 180).ToString();
  }
}
```